# Applying values to column and grouping all columns by those values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe as shown here. All lines without a value for `["sente"]` contain further information but they are yet not linked to `["sente"]`.

```
id    pos      value       sente
1     a         I           21
2     b         have        21
3     b         a           21
4     a         cat         21
5     d         !           21
6     cat       N           Nan
7     a         My          22
8     a         cat         22
9     b         is          22
10    a         cute        22
11    d         .           22
12    cat       N           NaN
13    cute      M           NaN
```

Now I want each row where there is no value in `["sente"]` to get its value from the row above. Then I want to group them all by `["sente"]` and create a new column with its content from the row without a value in `["sente"]`.

```
  sente      pos          value            content
   21     a,b,b,a,d   I have a cat !     'cat,N'
   22     a,a,b,a,d   My cat is cute .   'cat,N','cute,M'
```

This would be my first step:

`df.loc[(df['sente'] != df["sente"].shift(-1) & df["sente"] == Nan) , "sente"] = df["sente"].shift(+1)`

but it only works for one additional row not if there is 2 or more.

This groups up one column like I want it:

`df.groupby(["sente"])['value'].apply(lambda x: " ".join()`

But for more columns it doesn't work like I want:

`df.groupby(["sente"]).agr(lambda x: ",".join()`

Is there any way to do this without using stack functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#check NaNs values to boolean mask
m = df['sente'].isnull()
#new column of joined columns only if mask
df['contant'] = np.where(m, df['pos'] + ',' + df['value'], np.nan)
#replace to NaNs by mask
df[['pos', 'value']] = df[['pos', 'value']].mask(m)
print (df)
    id  pos value  sente contant
0    1    a     I   21.0     NaN
1    2    b  have   21.0     NaN
2    3    b     a   21.0     NaN
3    4    a   cat   21.0     NaN
4    5    d     !   21.0     NaN
5    6  NaN   NaN    NaN   cat,N
6    7    a    My   22.0     NaN
7    8    a   cat   22.0     NaN
8    9    b    is   22.0     NaN
9   10    a  cute   22.0     NaN
10  11    d     .   22.0     NaN
11  12  NaN   NaN    NaN   cat,N
12  13  NaN   NaN    NaN  cute,M
```

Last replace `NaN`s by forward filling with `ffill` and `join` with remove `NaN`s by `dropna`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df["sente"].ffill()).agg(lambda x: " ".join(x.dropna()))
print (df1)
             pos             value       contant
sente                                           
21.0   a b b a d    I have a cat !         cat,N
22.0   a a b a d  My cat is cute .  cat,N cute,M
```

Comment: This is a nice answer and works fine. I just can't run my script on it due to `["sente"]` becoming a float. How and why does this happen?

Comment: @ThelMi - In my opinion reason is some `NaN`. NaN by design is `float`, so cast all integers to floats. Check also [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#missing-data-casting-rules-and-indexing)

Comment: You're absolutely right. I really appreciate your help!